# Computer beep help! 1 beep, a pause, and followed by 2 beeps. The monitor does not display anything

Tags: bios

I am currently building a computer with a friend for a school project. After building it and connecting a monitor, we hear a beep, which is followed by 2 short beeps after a pause. So it goes like: BEEP ...... BEEP BEEP. We looked online for POST troubleshooting, and we are planning to take it to the technician, while I will be buying a VGA to HDMI cable because there might be something wrong with the monitor, because of how old it is. Can anybody help me? We are currently using x2 Crucial Ballistix 4GB, a Sapphire R9 280 3GB for a graphics card, and an Asus M5A-78L-M with USB3 for a motherboard. The processor, (which I do not believe to have the problem) is an AMD FX 6300. All the fans were working. Can you please help? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know. I have read and people say that it is a graphics card issue

Comment: Alright.  Well confirm its the graphics card then.  I very much doubt its the graphics card though.

Comment: [What does the beep code indicate the problem is?](http://support.asus.com/pcassistant/pdf/BeepTable_en-us.pdf)

Comment: It's very unlikely that every motherboard manufacturer would use the same beep code. It would be best to go to the manufacturer web site and get the user manual for the motherboard to confirm the error message.

Comment: [This seems to confirm](http://vip.asus.com/forum/view.aspx?id=20060321081927477&board_id=1&model=A8N-SLI+Premium&page=1&SLanguage=en-us) you need detectable memory to POST.

Comment: @ Ramhound, the beep will be continuous if it is a ram issue according to the link you posted. The long and 2 short beeps suggest a video card error. I looked on the ASUS site it confirmed video card, unless I am missing something... With that the simplest fix may be pulling and reseating the video card.

Comment: Does a "long beep" mean a beep, and then a pause, or a beep that lasts a longer duration?

Comment: I'd be careful not to confuse the first beep with the following ones. If the first beep is short, that could indicate that the 2 beeps are a HD fail, not a video issue. Also, the beep length is significant - one short 2 long could be video, though that would then boot to headless mode. If it booted headless, you'd see the HD indicator reading just like a regular boot. You would then be able to shut it down later with win/right/enter as normal